# Applying Möbius' theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

> 1. Let $\displaystyle T(Z)=\frac{z+1}{z+i}$. Find a straight line in $\mathbb{C}$ that is mapped by $T$ to a circle.
> 2. True or False: Every holomorphic function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ maps any straight line in $\mathbb{C}$ to either a circle or a straight line.

My Answer:

For  $z= 1+i,z= 1-i, z=-1-i$ substituted in $T$, I get $3$ distinct outputs: $z=1+i$ gives $\frac{4}{5}-\frac{3i}{5}$, $z=1-i$ gives $2-i$, and $z=-1-i$ gives $i$. Since these point are not in straight line then by Möbius' theorem it should be a circle.

Comment: Could someone suggest for improvements please.

Comment: The equations $z=1+i,z=1-i,z=-1-i$ determine three points, not three lines. These three points are not collinear (there is no line that passes through all three), so I don't really understand your argument.

Comment: @Avinesh you started with a non-line and it was mapped to a non-line. That was not your task.

Comment: @ Hagen von Eitzen: Then any suggestions for improvement. How do i start.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $T(z)\to\infty$ as $z\to -i$. Therefore to have a bounded (i.e. circular) image, the line must stay away from $-i$. Thus for example the real axis is such a line.

2 is trivially false, Try almost any function and almost any line (e.g. $z\mapsto (z+i)^2$ and the real axis).

Comment: so i have to take three points from the real line and substitue in T(Z) and check the results.